# File does not want to make a new directory (mkdir)?

Tags: java, file, while-loop, mkdir

So I'm trying to create a set of directories from a while loop.
The code for the file creating section is here:

```
File userDIR=new File("Folder1//"+VARIABLENUMBER+"//"+VARIABLENUMBER+"_Single.txt");
            boolean exists = userDIR.exists();
            System.out.println(userDIR);//prints correct location

            if (!exists) {
                System.out.println("does not exist");
                userDIR.mkdir();//THIS IS NOT HAPPENING
                System.out.println(userDIR.mkdir());//Prints FALSE?

            }else{
                System.out.println("File Found");
            }
```

If the folder path already exists it says it does... but if I try to create one - it doesn't work (just kind of skips) or says false...?

Can't work out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any comments or suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to use `userDir.mkdirs` not `mkdir`.

The difference is that the latter will try to create only the directory on the lowest level and if any of the parent directories does not exist it will fail. However, `userDir.mkdirs` will create any non-existing parent directories too.

Comment: AMAZING STUFF!! Didn't realise there was a mkdirs :) Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
userDIR.mkdir();
```

To:

```
userDIR.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to use mkdirs() Instead of mkdir(), secondly, If I'm not wrong exists(); return always true in case of directory, no matter if he is exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on windows? Shouldn't the file path be using backslahses \\ instead of // as specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29).